# What is the difference between static_cast and reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, c, casting, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

I'm using c function in c++, where a structure passed as a void type argument in c is directly stored that same structure type.

eg in C.

```
void getdata(void *data){
    Testitem *ti=data;//Testitem is of struct type.
}
```

to do the same in c++ i use static_cast:

```
void foo::getdata(void *data){
    Testitem *ti = static_cast<Testitem*>(data);
}
```

and when i use   `reinterpret_cast` it does the same job, casting the struct

when i use `Testitem *it=(Testitem *)data;`

this does the same thing too.
But how is the structure gets affected by using the three of them.

Comment: that thread says about when to use it. I'm asking about whats differs to that structure when using these three thing, and i forgot about dynamic_cast too.Simply put i wanna know how the structure is affected.

Comment: The structure isn't affected (unless casting between numeric types).

Comment: Casting from `void*` using `static_cast` and using `reinterpret_cast` gives the same result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68137312/5447906.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

A `static_cast` is a cast from one type to another that (intuitively) is a cast that could under some circumstance succeed and be meaningful in the absence of a dangerous cast.  For example, you can `static_cast` a `void*` to an `int*`, since the `void*` might actually point at an `int*`, or an `int` to a `char`, since such a conversion is meaningful.  However, you cannot `static_cast` an `int*` to a `double*`, since this conversion only makes sense if the `int*` has somehow been mangled to point at a `double*`.

A `reinterpret_cast` is a cast that represents an unsafe conversion that might reinterpret the bits of one value as the bits of another value.  For example, casting an `int*` to a `double*` is legal with a `reinterpret_cast`, though the result is unspecified.  Similarly, casting an `int` to a `void*` is perfectly legal with `reinterpret_cast`, though it's unsafe.

Neither `static_cast` nor `reinterpret_cast` can remove `const` from something.  You cannot cast a `const int*` to an `int*` using either of these casts.  For this, you would use a `const_cast`.

A C-style cast of the form `(T)` is defined as trying to do a `static_cast` if possible, falling back on a `reinterpret_cast` if that doesn't work.  It also will apply a `const_cast` if it absolutely must.

In general, you should always prefer `static_cast` for casting that should be safe.  If you accidentally try doing a cast that isn't well-defined, then the compiler will report an error.  Only use `reinterpret_cast` if what you're doing really is changing the interpretation of some bits in the machine, and only use a C-style cast if you're willing to risk doing a `reinterpret_cast`.  In your case, you should use the `static_cast`, since the downcast from the `void*` is well-defined in some circumstances.

Comment: It's also possible `double pi = 3.1415;
int ipi = static_cast<int>(pi);` but in case of link you must use reinterpret_cast `double* pi = 3.1415;
int* ipi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pi);`

Comment: Still very helpful answer! I'm writing custom allocators, and using `dynamic_cast` all the time to convert between `uintptr_t` and `void*`.

Comment: Neither ```static_cast``` nor ```reinterpret_cast``` can remove const from something. Directly usage, true, but passively usage, not true. Look at this: ```const int n = 9; const int* p = &n; int* i = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned>(p));``` This is for 32-bit platform and on 64-bit, change the ```unsigned``` to ```unsigned long long``` or use ```uintptr_t``` for both.