# Setting custom value to void pointer in gmock

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, pointers, googlemock

I am using Google Mock to unit test my C implementation. For one of my mock function the out parameter is defined as void pointer. The mock function is given below:

```
MOCK_METHOD3(file_read, int(const char *file_name, const char *type_name, void     *data_p));
```

According to [How to set a value to void * argument of a mock method in google mock testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788594/how-to-set-a-value-to-void-argument-of-a-mock-method-in-google-mock-testing)

I created an ACTION_P

```
ACTION_P(SetArg2ToMCValue, value) {   reinterpret_cast<void *>(arg2) = value; }
```

In my test code I set the default value to the parameter that is cast to void in ACTION_P and my expectation

```
  struct.a = 5.0;
  struct.b = 15.0;
  //Expectations
EXPECT_CALL(*libfile_mock,  file_read(_,_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArg2ToMCValue(&struct), Return(0)));
```

When the test is run, I do not see the custom values, I set to the struct. Rather I see 0. How do I set value to an out parameter that is also a void pointer in Google Mock?

Comment: After some search I found that arg2 will already be a void point and hence I need to cast it the struct type within ACTION_P


    ACTION_P(SetArg2ToMCValue, value) {   *reinterpret_cast<struct *>(arg2) = *value; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search I found that arg2 will already be a void pointer and hence I need to cast it to the struct type within ACTION_P.

```
ACTION_P(SetArg2ToMCValue, value) { *reinterpret_cast<struct *>(arg2) = *value; }
```

This worked.