# C++ malloc/memcpy/free crash

Tags: c++, templates, malloc, free, memcpy

I'am really stuck with this C++ error:

```
    template<typename T>
    void Shift(T* Data, const ulong& Length, long Offset) const
    {
        if((!Data) || (!Length))
            return;

        if(Offset < 0)
            Offset = (Length-1) - ((-Offset-1) % Length);
        else
            Offset %= Length;

        if(!Offset)
            return;

        int TSize = sizeof(T);

        T* Shifter = new T[Length];

        if(Shifter)
        {
            memcpy(Shifter, Data + TSize * Offset, TSize * (Length - Offset));
            memcpy(Shifter + TSize * (Length - Offset), Data, TSize * Offset); //fails
            memcpy(Data, Shifter, TSize * Length);

            delete[] Shifter;
        }
    }
```

Well, fail is:

77CD0575    ntdll!TpWaitForAlpcCompletion() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)

0028D640    ?? () (??:??)

77CB57C2    ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerDivide() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)

003E1030    ?? () (??:??)

77C92A8A    ntdll!RtlCopyExtendedContext() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??)

??  ?? () (??:??)

T is either byte of short, btw.

Comment: if it's C++, then don't use malloc/free, use new/delete

Comment: Using `rotate` might be safer.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you call it?

Comment: This code is evil, but if you comment out the memcpys one at a time you might find what's cuasing the problem

Comment: That `reinterpret_cast` is also wrong (should be `static_cast`)

Comment: What are the values of the Length and of the Offset?

Comment: Methinks it's UB unless T is a POD.

Comment: @MSalters why reinterpret_cast is wrong? I thought static_cast is weaker ...

Comment: @MSalters Nevermind, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855686/what-is-the-difference-between-static-cast-and-reinterpret-cast

Comment: reinterpret_cast is the most powerful than x_cast, guys

Comment: @AndreyMironov: Try `reinterpret_cast<int>(3.5)`. Not so powerful, eh?

Comment: casting:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lglGKxNrLgM
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfrR1nNfoeY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got the pointer arithmetics wrong. Let's say:

```
T* p = new T[10];
```

To get to the n'th element, you have to use

```
T* nth = p + n;
```

In your memcpy arguments you use it like

```
T* nth = p + sizeof(T) * n;
```

which will obviously be out of bounds at times.

Comment: But he can also convert the data and shifter pointer to void* as malloc and memcpy use void* in their prototypes. less expressive than C++ but...

Comment: @alexbuisson Not to void but to some byte-sized type, yes. void* does not allow pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 3):

in memcpy you are using Data + Offset*TSize which is incorrect when you say Data + 1 on case of an int the it actually takes 4 bytes, so you dont have to specify Tsize in case of pointer. Modify your memcpy code like this

```
memcpy(Shifter, Data + Offset, TSize * (Length - Offset));
memcpy(Shifter + (Length - Offset), Data, TSize * Offset); //fails if TSize is greater than 1
memcpy(Data, Shifter, TSize * Length);
```

Better explained by Timbo